# Multiple Background Image, Prevent overlapping

Tags: css

I'm using the following css code to get the background of a li to have a rounded rectangle with an arrow at the bottom.

```
background-image:url("../image/menu_button_active_left.png"), url("../image/menu_button_active_bg.png"), url("../image/menu_button_active_right.png"), url("../image/menu_button_active_bottom.png"); 
background-position:center left, center center, center right, center 43px; 
background-repeat:no-repeat, repeat-x, no-repeat, no-repeat
```

My problem is the image background_bg displayed above the background_left and background_right which prevents showing the rounded rectangle.

Also I want the background bottom to be at the z-index(top) ( I mean I want the background_bottom to hide 1px height at the bottom of background_bg, but now background_bg is at the z-index(top) hiding 1 px at the top of background_bottom image )

Please help me.

-------- SOLUTION FOR OVERLAPPING : FOUND --------

I tried

```
background-clip:border-box, content-box, border-box, border-box;
```

and it works very well.

Please help me to get the background_bottom_image to be placed above (like z-index) all the other background images.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for my problem.

```
background-clip:border-box, content-box, border-box, border-box;
```

used the above background-clip to make it a rounded rectangle

and used stack ordering, I put the bottom_background as the first to make it display above all other background_images

Thanks everyone.